# CSS not applying to VBox but will apply to it's children

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

In my main I load and set the VBox to an instance variable in the Controller:

```
FXMLLoader helpTipLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/helpTip.fxml"));
        setHelpTip(helpTipLoader.load());
```

The FXML file:

```
    <VBox fx:id="helpTip" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" 
styleClass="helpTip" stylesheets="@../css/main.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

And the .css

```
.helpTip{
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

.greenText{
    -fx-fill: lightgreen;
}
```

Now if I create a new Text object and give it the class name 'greenText' and add it to the helpTip VBox, and then add the VBox to the Scene's root - it will display with green text - however the Vbox itself seems to refuse to let the CSS apply to it. I'm at a complete loss here can anyone suggest why this weird behaviour is happening?

Comment: maybe your text object is in front of Vbox and you actually don't see it. Try to make empty Vbox without Text object and check if it has background color

Comment: Doesn't help I'm afraid. The setHelpTip() is a static setter which sets the static VBox instance variable in a Controller all other Controllers inherit from. Could this be affecting it?

Comment: Is the text box a child element of the <VBox>? If so, its styles will not be applied to its parent.

Comment: The textBox is added to the Children of the VBox yeah - but I don't see why the style won't apply. I can see it apply properly in Scene builder :/

Comment: For some reason if I take my root (A borderPane) and do root.setTop(getHelpTip()); it then behaves properly and loads the CSS, at the expensive of deleting whatever was in that part of my root. I'm so confused.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. The style is properly applied to the `VBox` and any shapes (such as `Text`) I add to the `VBox`. Voting for close since the issue is not reproducible with the code posted. Try creating a [mcve] and posting it in the question.